# How to change color of hyperref?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, citing

I'm using the

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt,fleqn]{article} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks= false, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
```

package, but I don't want to see red or green color in the document. I just want to have it white so that I can click on the reference or table or anything that is linked with hyperref. Is there a possibility?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use following. You can change colour as per your choice.

```
 \usepackage{hyperref}
 \hypersetup{
     colorlinks=true,
     linkcolor=blue,
     filecolor=blue,
     citecolor = black,      
     urlcolor=cyan,
     }
```

Comment: What if I want a colour is not predefined? For example, a dark green.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Then define that color first ---  e.g. \definecolor{pAlgae}{RGB}{87,115,135}

Answer (score 5):

To achieve no color in the hyperlinks use:

```
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
```

or:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks}
```

[Reference](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Hyperlinks#Customization)